# About partial class (...inaccessible due to its protection level)

Tags: c#

I have a partial class, called Point, and in them, I wanted to practice by createing a JustTest method, (which is pointless, because it just writes out a line), however I get this error "`Program.Point.JustTest()' is inaccessible due to its protection level".

```
public partial class Point
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point (int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    partial void JustTest();
}

public partial class Point
{
    partial void JustTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Should I work?");
    }

    public int setX
    {
        set
        {
            x = value;

        }
        get
        {
            return x;
        }
    }

    public int setY
    {
        set
        {
            y = value;

        }
        get
        {
            return y;
        }
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Point p1 = new Point(20,30);        
    p1.JustTest();
}
```

Comment: JustTest() is `private`. The partial part has nothing to do with this error, although you are using it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All members (methods and fields) of a class are private by default. All partial methods must be private.

So just change the line to:

```
public void JustTest() ...
```

and all will be fine.

Comment: Yeah, that works, however then I can't do `public void JustTest();`, and then at the other partial class the body of it. That's impossible to do, then?

Comment: @justrandomdude is there a reason you're looking to do that? Or is this just a learning exercise?

Comment: @justrandomdude, yes that's impossible. If you want to split the declaration and implementation you must make the method private.  Partial classes should be avoided as much as possible as they make the code very hard to read. Partial methods just compound that problem, so the whole thing ought to be moot anyway :).

Answer (score 5):

According to documentation:

> No access modifiers are allowed. Partial methods are implicitly private.

This justifies the error you are receiving regarding the method being inaccessible.

Maybe if you provided more context to what you are trying to achieve and why, more help could be provided.

[partial (Method)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6b0scde8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Partial methods are "*implicitly private, and therefore they cannot be virtual.*" nor can be access outside of the same class and modules. If you want it to be accessible outside you must declare public method that will access the partial methods. See explaination [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Any member within a class is `private` if nothing else is declared. Therefor the compiler-error is absolutely correct because you cannot access that private method `JustTest` within your `Program`-class.

Make `JustTest` public instead and omit the `partial`-definition because any `partial` member is implicitely `private`.